# How do I eliminate NPE with MainActivity Listener?

Tags: android, callback, android-edittext, listener

I am trying to have the MainActivity file have a listener to receive a callback from an EditText file.  The listener will be fired when the user presses the Back Button.  Since the soft keyboard will be open I'd like the onKeyPreIme function to capture the Back Button press so it can load a Toast and close the soft keyboard.  Attached are the two key files.  I know the onKeyPreIme function is not working because the listener is not loading the Toast in the MainActivity file.  Please advise.

MainActivity.java file:

```
import static com.example.jdw.secondscreen.ListenerEditText.KeyImeChange;

public class CardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Context context;

private ListenerEditText myListenerEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cardviewinput);

    myListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(R.id.CEditText);

    myListenerEditText.setKeyImeChangeListener(new KeyImeChange() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;

        }
    });  
...
```

ListenerEditText.java file:

```
public class ListenerEditText extends EditText {

private KeyImeChange keyImeChangeListener;

public ListenerEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setKeyImeChangeListener(KeyImeChange listener) {
    keyImeChangeListener = listener;
}

public interface KeyImeChange {
    boolean onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP &&
      keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
             if(keyImeChangeListener!= null) keyImeChangeListener.onKeyIme(keyCode, event);
    }
return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

**Logcat output:**

```
05-20 04:19:44.742  29155-29155/com.example.jdw.secondscreen E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
05-20 04:19:44.742  29155-29155/com.example.jdw.secondscreen E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
05-20 04:19:44.742  29155-29155/com.example.jdw.secondscreen E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
            at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
            at com.example.jdw.secondscreen.CardViewActivity$1.onKeyIme(CardViewActivity.java:31)
            at com.example.jdw.secondscreen.ListenerEditText.onKeyPreIme(ListenerEditText.java:34)
            at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(View.java:7060)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3511)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3113)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 04:19:44.742  29155-29155/com.example.jdw.secondscreen D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-20 04:19:44.742  29155-29155/com.example.jdw.secondscreen W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6263288)
05-20 04:19:44.742  29155-29155/com.example.jdw.secondscreen E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
            at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
            at com.example.jdw.secondscreen.CardViewActivity$1.onKeyIme(CardViewActivity.java:31)
            at com.example.jdw.secondscreen.ListenerEditText.onKeyPreIme(ListenerEditText.java:34)
            at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(View.java:7060)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(ViewGroup.java:1339)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3511)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3113)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               ^^^^^
```

`context` is `null`

Initialize `context` before passing to `makeText` method:

```
context=CardViewActivity.this;
```

or directly use `CardViewActivity.this` to show Toast message instead of using unnecessary variables :

```
Toast.makeText(CardViewActivity.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Nice catch!  No more crash.  Thank you!

Comment: One more issue remains.  I'd like the Back Button press to bring the user to the previous activity (screen) as well as close the soft keyboard.  Do I need to add "return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event) so that a single press of the Back Button closes the soft keyboard and returns the user to the previous activity?

Comment: @AJW: search on stackoverflow lots of post related to same issue